# How is this read correctly in maths , and meaning (about: sets)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

> $J \subseteq \left\{1,2,..,n\right\}$ is an index set ....   Fix $J
> \subseteq \left\{1,2,..,n\right\}$ and let $S=\left\{x_j : j \in
> J\right\}$

The problem I'm having here is "Fix" , what does that mean ? I think "fix" refers to some constant value, or in this case SOME set we are chosing?

My other question is how is the set $S$ read correctly? I would read it like that: The set $S$ contains elements $x_j$ where each index $j$ is from index set $J$"

I hope someone can help :)

Comment: I think the text is being weird in that the time to "fix" a set is when you introduce it.  "fix" here means what you think it means.  $J$ is a *specific* set and we are "fixing" it to so it is a *particular* set.  And you interpretation of $S$ is correct. Example: if $X=\{x_1,x_2,......,x_{17}\}$ and $J = \{1,5,8,9,13\}$ (and $J$ is *fixed* to be that exact set) then $S = \{x_1,x_5,x_8,x_9,x_{13}\}$.  All it is saying is if $S\subset X$ we can refer to the index value of the set $S$ (and vice versa).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "fix" means "consider some particular $J$" or "for each $J$ define $S$ to be ..." . Your description of $S$ in terms of $J$ is correct.

No need to overthink this.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the word "fix", since logically speaking what is going on here is that we want to consider **any arbitrary given** $J ⊆ \{1..n\}$. Much better would be something like "**Take any** $J ⊆ \{1..n\}$, and let $S = \cdots$. Then . . .". But why do people use this word? It is because in their mind they are thinking that they want to *temporarily* focus on one specific $J$ and reason about that set together with another set $S$ associated with that particular $J$. So this becomes "let's fix $J$ *for now*, and define $S$ in terms of *this* $J$, and ...". Of course, in the end we are **not** talking about only one *constant fixed* $J$. This notion can be made clear in Fitch-style natural deduction:

[We want to prove $∀n{∈}ℕ\ ∀J{⊆}\{1..n\}\ ( \ Q(n,J) \ )$.]
Given $n{∈}ℕ$ and $J{⊆}\{1..n\}$:
  [It suffices to prove $Q(n,J)$ in this subcontext (i.e. with $n{∈}ℕ$ and $J{⊆}\{1..n\}$ *given* to you).]
  [Note that in this subcontext you have *no control* over $n,J$; they are fixed here.]
  $\vdots$
  $Q(n,J)$.
$∀n{∈}ℕ\ ∀J{⊆}\{1..n\}\ ( \ Q(n,J) \ )$.   [In the conclusion $n,J$ are of course not fixed.]